# .htaccess subdomains to _GET

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to use .htaccess rewriting to redirect subdomains to PHP variables.

I'd like it to work like this:

User enters:
subdomain.domain.com/randompage
Page redirects to:
domain.com/index.php?sub=subdomain&page=randompage
But the user doesn't see the URL change.

Kind of like how this works but with the subdomains:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

This is my first time using stackoverflow, thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?sub=%1&page=$1 [QSA,L]
```